Compute the Picard group of the intersection of two quadric surfaces
The question is :Let C be the intersection of two quadric surfaces
given
by
C:{ $ x_ {0}^ {2} $ + $ x_ {1}^ {2} $ + $ x_ {2}^ {2} $ + $ x_ {3}^ {2} $ = $ x_ {0}^ {2} $ + $ x_ {1} $$ x_ {2} $ + $ x_ {3} $$ x_ {1} $ + $ x_ {2} $$ x_ {3} $ =0} $ \subseteq $ $ P^ {3} $ ,compute the picard group of C.I don't know how to compute the picard group without knowing the curve of the intersection.I think there might be some way to solve the curve explicitly? I just have learnt chapter 2 of Hartshorne,sorry that I may not own enough tools to solve it.

Before you can apply any of the machinery of Hartshorne Chapter 2 you will need to understand the geometry of $C$ a bit more. By definition it is a curve of degree 4 on a quadric surface in $\mathbf P^3$ --- what else can you say about it? Is it singular or nonsingular, reducible or irreducible? If it is reducible, what do its components look like? How do they intersect? Answering these questions will get you a good part of the way to the solution.

@Lazzaro Campeotti .I see,but that's the part that stucks me,I don't know how to get a easier form of that curve.

I suggest to start by computing its singular locus. Then (if you haven't already) read what Hartshorne or another book says about curves on smooth quadric surfaces.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5012413
