Picard group of a "rhombus" in $\mathbb{P}^3_{\mathbb{C}}$
I was asked to compute the Picard group of
$$
C:\{x_0^2+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2=x_0^2+x_1x_2+x_3x_1+x_2x_3=0\} \subseteq \mathbb{P}^3_{\mathbb{C}},
$$
and I have found that $C$ is four projective lines
$$
\begin{align}
&l_1:\lambda[0,1,\omega,\omega^2]+\mu[1,-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}},-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}},-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}] \\
&l_2:\lambda[0,1,\omega,\omega^2]+\mu[1,\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}] \\
&l_3:\lambda[0,1,\omega^2,\omega]+\mu[1,-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}},-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}},-\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}] \\
&l_4:\lambda[0,1,\omega^2,\omega]+\mu[1,\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}},\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}],
\end{align}
$$
where $\omega$ is the 3rd unit root. How to compute the picard group of this "rhombus"? I tried to use the exact sequence associated to
$$
0\to \mathcal{O}_C^\times \to (\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}^\times)^4 \to \mathcal{F} \to 0,
$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ is the skyscraper sheaf supported on four singular points of $C$, but I can't figure out the boundary morphism.

A quadruple of invertible functions on the components glue into an invertible function on the "rhombus" if and only if the restrictions of the functions to intersection points agree.

You don't need to compute the boundary morphism, but only to find the dimension of the image of $H^0((\mathcal O^\times_{\mathbb P^1})^4)\to H^0(\mathcal F)$ and use that $H^1(\mathcal F)=0$. Then you can interpret the answer by noting that the kernel of $H^1(\mathcal O_C^\times)\to H^1((\mathcal O^\times_{\mathbb P^1})^4)$ corresponds to different ways of gluing the structure sheaves of 4 lines in intersection points.
